# Which is more natural: peer or peer groups?

Tags: word-choice

I ran an experiment on a website where I allocated different users into different groups. (Example: if there were six users: A, B, C, D, E, and F, it could be that users A, B, and C were allocated to group 1, while D, E, F were allocated to group 2, and users in group 1 only saw each other and not users of group 2, and likewise users of group 2 only saw users of group 2.)

I found that user behavior was affected by the other users in that user's group. Which is more appropriate:

1. I find that one's contributions are significantly affected by one's peer group.
2. I find that one's contributions are significantly affected by one's peers.

Or something else?

Comment: If I take 6 people who are peers and divide them into two groups, are the peers that end up in different groups no longer peers?

Comment: Yes, they are no longer peers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of your example sentences clearly describes the situation without the need for further context.

For something more inclusive to a single sentence, I would, as you suggested, try something else:

> I found that the contributions of each member of a group were affected by the other members within the same group.

Answer (score -1):

Your question states:

> I allocated different users into different groups.

**You** did the allocating. The group membership was determined by you and your methods. Peer groups and their members, peers, are based on age, status and interest. These are intrinsic qualities of the volunteers in your study. They can't be allocated by the researcher.

[Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/peer_group)

> #### peer group:
>
> A group of people of approximately the same age, status, and interests.

[Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/peer)

> #### peer
>
> 2. A person of the same age, status, or ability as another specified person.

Comment: In "a jury of your peers" I'd wager that very few of the people on the jury are of the same age, status, and interests as the accused.  Except if you say that by *status* it means, a civilian.

Comment: @Jim "jury of your peers" is a legal phrase with a specific meaning. "In respect of civil rights, all citizens are equal before the law. The humblest is the peer of the most powerful." - Harlan's dissent in Plessy v. Ferguson, chnm.gmu.edu/courses/nclc375/harlan.html  Regardless, it's an intrinsic characteristic, and shouldn't be used to describe group allocation in a study.

Comment: My point was that I think your definition is rather simplistic.  When I think of my peers at work, they are not necessarily of the same age or ability as me.  And to say that peer groups are based on age, status and interest is a bit misleading.

Comment: @Jim your quarrel is with the [oxford dictionary](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/), not me. As far as a working environment is, I'd say my peers are the people who have a similar position and seniority. Others would be my colleagues.